# ASP.NET Core 2.x defaults to non-existent route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How to change the default route in ASP.NET Core

the route is very strange it is actually the

> api/values

which doesn't exist anymore, I've deleted the controller and that was it, 
I just created a Home controller and the rest of them are APIs. 
Why is there still this route present ?

This is the controller which i want to default to

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return new RedirectResult("~/swagger");
        }
    }
```

I've tried this answer

[.net Core - Default controller is not loading when Route attribute is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875969/net-core-default-controller-is-not-loading-when-route-attribute-is-used)

but doesn't work for me

this is my configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .AddMvc(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); 
}


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
       app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
 }
```

Comment: Why do you even want a single controller for redirecting to the swagger UI? Just register SwaggerUI as described in the docs. There you can configure the endpoint under which swagger ui will be available ...

Comment: swagger is just an example, I could use anything over there, the idea remains, why doesn't it work ?  and why do I see a route that should't exist ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a **launchSettings.json** where is under the properties. You can change **launchUrl** field with your default route.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63986",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values", //change here
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values", //change here
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```